# What's this web background scrolling effect called?

Tags: css

Hey all this is my first question on here go easy on me. I'm learning CSS3 and came across an effect that I wanted to use. I'm not sure if it's simply classed as parallax scrolling or if there is a specific name for it.

The effect doesn't show on mobiles...

http://www.anotherstory.co/home/

At certain points scrolling down there is a different static background behind the content. What is it called and how is it achieved? Any links to references would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Refere This https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it's called, but it's achieved like this (extra stuff removed):

```
// first div
.intro-text {
    background: #fb860a url("../css/images/Office2.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover ;
}

// second div
div.Services {
    background: #454545 url("../css/images/Office3.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallax is an effect where we have the objects positioned at same line of sight but they move at different speeds when we scroll our page this creates an illusion of objects moving at different speeds.

Refer This link 
 http://www.uiupdates.com/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-scrolling-webpage/